# Unable to use source command within python script

Tags: python

I basically want to set path for some of the variables in Unix. But the source command does not work here. Any suggestions of the same?

Comment: It would helpful if you could provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: you talking about environment variables? give a read at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235435/environment-variables-in-python-on-linux)

Comment: I understand that you're using Python. I think you're trying to use a bash command in Python. That obviously doesn't work since bash and python are different languages. But I don't understand what you're trying to do. Post your code, and explain what you want it to do.

Answer (score 5):

I tried what you describe and the solution is to use `.` instead of `source`, which is basically an alias of the former.
You also must explicitly specify `./FILENAME` if the file in the current directory.

Please see my example session:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("source .bashrc")
sh: 1: source: not found
32512
>>> os.system(". .bash_aliases")
sh: 1: .: .bash_aliases: not found
512
>>> os.system(". ./.bash_aliases")
0
>>> os.system(". ~/.bash_aliases")
0
>>> os.system(". /home/USERNAME/.bash_aliases")
0
```

A return value of `0` indicates success.

However, I am not sure if sourcing a file this way produces the results you want, as this method runs the given command in a subshell and I am not sure if this also affects the shell session you want.

Comment: @MikhileshSekhar Instead of writing "Thank you!" comments, please click the grey tick button on the left of this answer to **accept** it. Make sure you have read the short info [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and have checked out the [tour] page to learn the most important stuff about how this site works. Thanks! :-)